# UnsatisfiedLinkError on Websphere Application Server 6.1 Data Source

Tags: java, oracle, websphere

I am unable to start the installed App on my WAS instance. I believe the root cause is an UnsatisfiedLinkError which is shown as follows:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc10 in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1682)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:993)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3147)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:3143)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:221)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.(T2CConnection.java:132)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:78)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
 at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:297)
 at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:515)
 at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:159)
 at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:133)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:935)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:972)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:1625)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1220)
 at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:1988)
 at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1660)
 at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2341)
 at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:932)
 at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:608)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:449)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:418)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.ConnectionFactoryAbstractImpl.newConnectionFromDataSource(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.ConnectionFactoryAbstractImpl.lookupConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.ConnectionFactoryManagedImpl.lookupConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.ConnectionManagerImpl.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.StatementManager.getPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.JdbcAccessImpl.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.RsQueryObject.performQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.accesslayer.RsIterator.(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.RsIteratorFactoryImpl.createRsIterator(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getRsIteratorFromQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getIteratorFromQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.QueryReferenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.QueryReferenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.QueryReferenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.PersistenceBrokerImpl.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.DelegatingPersistenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.ojb.broker.core.DelegatingPersistenceBroker.getCollectionByQuery(Unknown Source)
 at com.ascential.xmeta.persistence.orm.impl.ojb.OjbPersistentEObjectPersistenceRegistry.loadPackageCache(OjbPersistentEObjectPersistenceRegistry.java:371)
 ... 115 more

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable for the 'was' user is /opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib

What else should I be checking to fix this error?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Verify that "Java Library Path" in the trace header of SystemOut.log contains "/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib".  If it does not contain the path, then your LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting is not taking effect (perhaps the variable isn't exported, or perhaps you're executing startServer as a different user).

Regardless, I would recommend setting adding "/opt/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib" to the native library path of the JDBC provider rather than trying to set it at the OS level.

Finally, double-check that the server has the proper OS permissions to access the native library.